# Alternative to COUNTIF in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, countif

I used `COUNTIF` on SQL Server to `COUNT` a particular value with condition but it brought out an error.

```
SELECT 
    total rounds, total member, total customer,
    ROUND(total rounds/total member, 2) * 100 AS memberper
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(rideid) total rounds
         COUNTIF(member_customer = 'member') AS total member,
         COUNTIF(member_customer = 'customer') AS total customer
     FROM 
         Data)
```

Comment: `COUNTIF` is an Excel function. You're looking for `CASE`. I recommend you find a good SQL tutorial to learn the basics of the language - doing so will save you a lot of frustration going forward.

Comment: And once you have had a crack and got stuck, when asking a question provide sample data and desired results i.e. a [mre]

Comment: Ok I know about CASE didn't know I had to use it in this certain condition thanks.

Comment: `sum(case when member_customer = 'member' then 1 else 0 end)`.